# C# .NET 4 Table missing columns? asp:Table

Tags: c#, sql, .net, html-table

I have a SQL query used in a stored procedure. This runs by itself and when debugging, returns all the data. There are 16 columns. When this table loads on the webpage, there are 14 columns, and the missing ones are (counting from 0) column 1 and column 4.

Here is the code that loads the table in the .aspx file.

```
<asp:Table ID="tbl" runat="server" 
     CssClass="display cell-border nowrap table-responsive tableFixHead w-100 text-center tblGradient mt-2">
</asp:Table>
```

Here is the code that calls loads the data into the tbl element.

```
protected void buildTableHeader()
{
     TableHeaderRow tRowsHeader = new TableHeaderRow();
     TableHeaderCell tCell = new TableHeaderCell();

     foreach (DataColumn column in dtEmp.Columns)
     {
        tCell = new TableHeaderCell();
        tCell.Text = column.ToString(); // write column names to header cells
        tRowsHeader.Cells.Add(tCell);
     }

     tRowsHeader.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;

     tbl.Rows.Add(tRowsHeader);
  }

  protected void buildTableEmpData()
  {
     TableRow row = new TableRow();
     TableCell cell = new TableCell();

     foreach (DataRow dr in dtEmp.Rows)
     {
        row = new TableRow();

        foreach (DataColumn column in dtEmp.Columns)
        {
           cell = new TableCell();
           cell.Text = dr[column.ColumnName].ToString();
           row.Cells.Add(cell);

           if (column.ColumnName == "Description" && cell.Text.ToString() == " ")
           {
              row.Attributes.Add("class", "totalRow");
           }
        }

        tbl.Rows.Add(row);
     }
  }

  protected void buildTable()
  {
     tbl.Visible = true;
     //Table Header -----------------------------------------------
     buildTableHeader();

     //Table Data -------------------------------------------------
     buildTableEmpData();
  }
}
```

When debugging, I put a breakpoint after the `buildTableHeader()` function, and the tbl element has one row with 16 cells:

[image: tbl debugging]

After the table is completely built, there are still 16 columns:

[image: tbl debugging 2]

But when the page loads there are only 14 columns.

Here is the HTML:

[image: HTML tbl]

As far as I can tell, the tbl element has all the required data. Why is it not being loaded into the HTML?

Edit: I removed two columns to see if the columns I was missing would come back. One of them did, but a different one is now missing, and the table is still down two columns. It's still Column 1 and 4 that are missing.

Answer (score 0):

I did a search for "visible" and found that in my .aspx file, I had these lines of code buried in a `<script type="text/javascript">` tag:

```
columnDefs: [
    { "visible": false, "targets": [1, 4] }
],
```

After commenting them out, the columns were visible again.